# How to respond to clicks in TableView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This sounds quite simple, but I haven't found anything like that in the web. How to add click listeners to data rows in TableView?

Comment: can you post your code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what I've found so far, is that while you cannot add any type of input listeners to the TabeView itself, you can add `Tapped` event listener to the ViewCells inside it. This seems to be working:

```
var cell = new CustomCell();
cell.Tapped += OnCellTapped;
tableView.Root.LastOrDefault().Add(cell);
....
private void OnWalletTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetHashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the root element within your custom `ViewCell`. That way you can bind the gesture recognizer to a Command with command parameters.

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding CustomCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Thing}" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```